# Is there a way to set all newly created subfolders within a folder to have a specific owner automatically?

Tags: bash

I have a specific file structure:

```
/home 
     /MCDS
         /paper
         ...
     /TFDS
         ...
```

If a program executed by the MCDS user creates a folder in /home/MCDS, its ownership is automatically set to the root user. Is there any way to automatically make all folders created in the main folder (in this case /home/MCDS) owned by the user that executed the program (MCDS) or owned by MCDS automatically?

Comment: Do you mean `/MCDS` or `/home/MCDS`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Does the problem with root-owned directories occur only with a specific program? (Which one?) Is it a setuid-root program? If you don't know, run `type your_program` and show the output of `ls -l /path/to/your_program`. Please also show the output of `ls -ld /home/MCDS`.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `inotifywait`.